# Google Wallet & Multiple Payees

Tags: integration, android-pay

I am interested in understanding if Google Wallet supports multiple payees from a single source application.  I am familiar with Paypal IPN integrations; in these you can specify the destination account; I am looking to do something similar with Google Wallet.

The web application I am working on is a multi-tenant application where payments will need to be routed accordingly.

I am coming up empty in my google and stack overflow searches.  Any help is appreciated.  Need more details?  Fire away!

Paypal IPN Info: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

Comment: You might have already realized that Google Wallet wasn't meant to replace a payment gateway such as Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already realized that Google Wallet wasn't meant to replace a payment gateway such as Stripe.  Say you're building an app on android, you can integrate a button "Pay with Google" , this will now be called Android Pay. Your app will request access to credit card, shipping info and if user agrees , you can then pass it through Stripe or other payment gateways (stripe supports destination)